# Ambiguous question in visa application: Have you lived for at least two years in the country where you are applying visa?

Tags: visa, india, language

I'm applying for an visa in India and got this question in their online registration form with a yes/no answer:

> Have you lived for at least two years in the country where you are applying visa?

Does it mean the country from which I'm applying or the country where I'm applying to (i.e.: India)? It sounds weird they would say country instead of simply India if they are asking if I lived in India.

Comment: Your quote is grammatically incorrect. Could you edit it to show the exact words given in the application form?

Comment: @user16259 That's the exact quote and the reason for the question. I was sent here from the English Language Learners StackExchange.

Comment: I’ve been in India for one year. Now I want to apply for an Evisa. I don’t want to have to go back to the UK to get a visa that I can apply for online, I want to apply from another country. Is this possible? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the context I believe they are talking about the country from which you are making the application.

My assumption is that if you were, say, a Columbian citizen who has been living in France for the last 1 year and applying via the Indian Embassy in Paris, you may be asked for additional information or documents that someone (of any nationality) who has lived in France for the last 3 years would not be asked for.

Further, if you had been living in India for the last 2 years you would perhaps be applying for a new residence permit rather than a visa.

Comment: In the end I chose to interpret it like this.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It is exactly what I needed to know. I wish they would make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the question anywhere in the application form, but it was there when I finished filling it in, already answered... with a yes.... So I'm assuming they meant from the country where you are applying from.

Comment: Hi, ultimately I got the visa approved so I think yes, that's what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

It means currently where you are located, take a look at here:

> **[What to type exactly for "Have you lived at least 2 years in the country where you're applying visa?" to get your visa
> approved](https://tamilfunda.com/have-you-lived-at-least-two-years-in-country-where-applying-visa/)**

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is wrong and they should fix it. It is clearly confusing that we have to come discuss it here or look around on google to understand what it means. Very careless. To answer the question...

It refers to the country where you are located at the time of applying for the indian e visa.